# ¿How to save a session in CARLA?

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I have upgraded Ubuntu Studio 19.10 to 20.04 and now I have two big problems I can't repair:

1. Now CARLA takes a long time to open a session that have a Kontakt as a VST plugin but doesn't run Kontakt, one have to remove Kontakt plugin and then charge again as the first time, one have to do this everytime using CARLA.
2. Ubuntu-Studio doesn't detect the TV as a audio output hardware by HDMI,only transmit image but not sound.